# How to make Android animation to circle like in Moves app

Tags: android, android-animation

can anyone help me figure out how to make this animation done in Moves app for their circles. I have attached a GIF explaining it.

I clicked three times on the circle and each time I click, the animation is done.

It would be great if I could do it using ViewPropertyAnimator API.

[The GIF is available here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-bBKRFgI4xMU3BrRnJSZkZ3aDA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I couldn't upload the GIF directly to the question...

Comment: Make a gif and display that while your app is loading..

Comment: @HopeRunsDeep but I want this to be done on user's click on the circle. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: you want the animation to end when the user clicks on it 3 times? I don't understand.

Comment: @HopeRunsDeep No, animation only runs once per click.

Comment: You have to show us your code

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a `ScaleAnimation`.
In code, that could look something like this:

```
ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1.20f, 1f, 1.20f, centerX, centerY);
anim.setDuration(100);
anim.setRepeatCount(2);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
view.startAnimation(anim);
```

in XML:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:duration="100"
   android:fromXScale="1"
   android:fromYScale="1"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:repeatCount="2"
   android:repeatMode="reverse"
   android:toXScale="1.25"
   android:toYScale="1.25" />
```

the double pulse is due to the repeat count being set to 2, play around with it and see what settings work the best for you.

Comment: Can I do this with `ViewPropetyAnimator` ?

Comment: `ViewPropetyAnimator` does not support repeat.